# Agricola - Brushwood Collector + Carpenter's Parlor combination

Tags: agricola

So, let's say I have the improvement "Carpenter's Palror", which allows wooden rooms to cost 2 wood and 2 reed.

Then see Brushwood Collector: Each time you renovate or build a room, you can replace the required 1 or 2 reed with a total of 1 wood.

If you interpret this combination in the order Parlor then Brushwood:

It costs 2 wood and 2 reed, then the 2 reed is replaced with 1 wood. So it now costs 3 wood.

In the other order:

It now costs 6 wood in total (brushwood), then the entire cost is set to 2 wood and 2 weed (2 wood and 2 reed).

Which is the appropriate interpretation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**You could build a wooden room for 3 wood.**

Carpenter's Parlor sets the base cost, and Brushwood Collector allows you to pay part of the cost differently. Essentially, they don't even interact, since the Parlor is changing the wood cost of wooden rooms and the Collector is changing the reed cost of building/renovation.